# I need to retrieve the name of an array instead of the data contained within

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

If I have

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]    
array2 = [a,b,c,d,e,f]   
array = [array1,array2]
```

Is there a way to print the name of the array using print `array[0]` and get `array1` and not the elements of `array1`. When I run:

```
print array[0]
output: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, and the subsequent discussion, is sounds as if the names of the arrays matter as much to you as the actual contents.  Perhaps you are using the wrong data structure, and instead should be using a hash.  For example:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]    
array2 = [a,b,c,d,e,f]   
ahash = {'array1': array1, 'array2': array2}
```

Then you get the names of all the components:

```
print ahash.keys()
['array1', 'array2']
```

Or the values of just one named component:

```
print ahash['array1']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note that you can't rely upon the order of the keys unless you sort them,
so even though `ahash.keys()` returns you an array of keys, it is only a coincidence that they happen to be in the right order above, so you can't rely upon `ahash.keys()[0]` being `'array1'`.

Comment: This also helped me in an Ansible playbook to find the name of the arrays while iterating over facts dictionary. One can find the name of the first array as `{{ item.value.keys().0 }}`. Just keep on increasing the counter to print further array names.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string array called 'array' where you add in the names of the different arrays you have, and then array[0] should output array1.

Comment: What if I don't know the names of an array because they are being read in from a file, is it possible then?

Comment: If they are read in, you can create an array to read each in, but have the array have one extra index, and that index is the identification number of the array. (So this can be in index 0 for simplicity, and then you populate the other indices with the array numbers.) Then, in your larger array, you can store these arrays and when you call array[i], you return the first index of the array in the ith position.